# Set Based Table Filtering using Table-Valued Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to see if there is a Set Based way of filtering Table Data given a Table-Valued Parameter as an input to a UDF or SPROC.

The data table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE activity
(
     id int identity primary key, 
     employeeId int NOT NULL,
     stationId char(1) NOT NULL,
     type int NOT NULL
);
```

The Table-Valued Parameter is defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE activityType AS TABLE(
    stationId char(1) NOT NULL,
    type int NOT NULL
);
```

Given the following Table data:

```
INSERT INTO activity
(employeeId, stationId, type)
VALUES
(100, 'A', 1), (100, 'B', 2), (100, 'C', 3),
(200, 'A', 1), (200, 'B', 2), (200, 'D', 1),
(300, 'A', 2), (300, 'C', 3), (300, 'D', 2);
```

I would like to be able to filter given a particular TVP from the UI.

**Example 1**: Find all employeeId who performed Activity 1 @ Station A AND Activity 2 @ Station B

```
DECLARE @activities activityType;

INSERT INTO @activities
VALUES('A', 1),('B', 2)
```

Expected Result from applying this TVP:

```
employeeId
-----------------
100
200
```

**Example 2:** Find all employeeId who performed Activity 1 @ Station A, Activity 2 @ Station B, AND Activity 3 @ Station C

```
DECLARE @activities activityType;

INSERT INTO @activities
VALUES('A', 1),('B', 2),('C', 3);
```

Expected Result from applying this TVP:

```
employeeId
-----------------
100
```

I can apply this filter by looping over the TVP and intersecting the individually filtered results.  However, I have the gut feeling there is a Set Based approach using CTEs or MERGE that I just can't wrap my head around at the moment.

Comment: So , where is your question?

Comment: What would be the appropriate Set Based SQL query to filter the activity table data given a Table Valued Parameter with an arbitrary number of activityType rows.  Effectively I'm trying to create a function FindEmployeeByStationActivities(@activities activityType READONLY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the perfect solution, but you could try something as next:

```
DECLARE @ExpectedActivities int

SELECT
    @ExpectedActivities = COUNT(*)
FROM
    @activities

SELECT
   *
FROM
    activity A
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            NA.employeeId
        FROM
            activity NA
            INNER JOIN @activities FA ON FA.stationId  = NA.stationId
                AND FA.type = NA.type
        GROUP BY
            NA.employeeId
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) >= @ExpectedActivities
    ) B ON A.employeeId = B.employeeId
```

Comment: I believe this would have problems if the same activity is performed twice. Example: (100, 'A', 1),(100,'A',1),(100,'B',2),(100,'C',3) in the data table.

Comment: The question does not mention anything about business rules on repeated activities. You can always use distinct, partition by, etc. to meet your more granular requirements.

Comment: The quantity of repeated activities really is negligible as long as the provided activity is counted at least once. I believe this approach may be the best path forward.  I'll report back after attempting.

Comment: I believe this approach coincides with Felix Pamittan [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012682/set-based-table-filtering-using-table-valued-parameter/44013197#44013197).  I appreciate the help in moving in the right direction on this.

Comment: Cool! Then flag the answer you think is right to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

For scenario 1 - You could `inner join` with the table valued parameter itself. For the second scenario, you could do:

```
select distinct a.employeeId 
from #activity as a
inner join @activities as b on b.stationId = a.stationId and b.type = a.type
```

For the second scenario:

```
   select distinct act.employeeId 
   from #activity as act 
   where act.employeeId not in (
          select distinct a.employeeId from #activity as a
          left join @activities as b on b.stationId = a.stationId and b.type = a.type
          where b.stationId is null)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the amount of OR predicates depends on the arbitrary number of rows in the TVP.  This can be done with dynamic sql, but I prefer to not open that can of worms.

Comment: I think the join would work just fine. Did you try that? Nevermind, that only works for the first scenario..

Comment: @UbuntuUser - please see the update. I think that works. Please let me know if there is problem, cuz I want this solved as well haha

Answer (score 0):

This is a Relational Division with no Remainder problem. Dwain Camps has an article about this with a number of solutions:

[High Performance Relational Division in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/)

```
SELECT a.employeeId 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT employeeId, stationId, type 
    FROM activity
) a
INNER JOIN @activities at
    ON a.stationId = at.stationId
    AND a.type = at.type
GROUP BY
    a.employeeId
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @activities);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/671736)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you.  This is the most informative answer.  I appreciate the pedagogy in your answer as well as the highly informative article on this topic.

Comment: @UbuntuUser Thanks. You formed your question very well.